# How can I mask Email Addresses in Java 1.6

Tags: java

I am currently working with developers as an IT Security Enginneer. As part of PCI compliance and in an attempt to ensure that Personal Identifiable Information is protected, there is a requirement to mask client email addresses prior to writting those addresses to log files.
Can someone provide me with some help on how to accomplish this.
Our development environment is Java 1.6. I will appreciate any help and I thank you all in advance.

Comment: What's your logging framework? Log4j etc?

Comment: Yes, we are using Log4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Log4J (which you've indicated you are), you could write your own [Layout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html).

You could extend say [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html), delegate to the super class to do the heavy lifting, then mask the email in the response.

```
/**
 * Mask email addresses in logging lines.
 */
public class MaskingLayout extends PatternLayout {
    private static Pattern EMAIL = Pattern.compile("([^.@\\s]+)(\\.[^.@\\s]+)*@([^.@\\s]+\\.)+([^.@\\s]+)");

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        Matcher matcher = EMAIL.matcher(super.format(event));
        return matcher.replaceAll("xxx@xxx.xxx");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to log email addresses, I suggest you generate a md5 from the user's email. It will not be reversible and should be unique per email.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Comment: Just for sake of completeness, there are way better options available as MD5: One of them is SHA-512 for example. Even though it is not being used for password protection, I would not rely on an algorithm that is now already proven to be showing it's cracks.

Comment: sure, sha-256 or sha-512 are stronger than md5. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: We are also logging other information, except that we want the PII such as email address to be masked. They are only collecting the email address for debugging purposes so there might be a need for it to be reversible.

Comment: BTW, PCI asks that you protect it, there is no need to make it unreversable. So you can also you a simple an encryption with a known key (to your code). That would also satisfy PCI